# Should the "stressors" question have been left open?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am referring to this question:

- [What stressors do programmers encounter on the job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/74913/3249)

I can see that one of the moderators stepped in and added some guidance for answers, but it sure doesn't look like anybody took it seriously, and the question itself seems like a pure "pet peeve" poll.

Is there something I'm missing?  What redeeming value is there in a question like this?  How is it any different from simply asking *"What do you hate about being a programmer?"*

Questions about dealing with *specific* impediments are great - I even answered one about [getting better requirements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/67923/3249), that being the #1 item on the list in Joel's (accepted) answer.  Of course, the 3 line blurb there is (no offense to Joel) really not going to help any programmer be better at his/her job, whereas the former targeted question at least has a chance.  The "stressors" question is really just yet another bitch-fest, pardon my French.

Ordinarily I'd just flag these questions, but since it's already picked up a ridiculous number of votes *and* been touched by at least one moderator, I figured it made more sense to ask for clarification.

Comment: Couldn't agree more and am surprised it only has 2 close votes.

Comment: I saw the original question and that it had been edited by another moderator. As it didn't (and still doesn't) have any flags it's simply not on my list of posts to look at. Perhaps that's my mistake.

Comment: @Chris: This question isn't necessarily just for the moderators, it's for the entire community.  Like Walter, I'm surprised that the *community* didn't close it immediately - perhaps they saw the moderator edit and considered that to be a pass.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/whats-your-least-favorite-thing-about-programming (and closed) (FWIW, I hate both questions, but allow that for whatever reason these *are* among the topics that folks really *wanted* P.SE to exist for - whether they can be shepherded into some useful form or not is going to depend largely on how much effort the community (including moderators) wants to put into cleaning up cruft... (including responses such as my answer to the first question))

Comment: How could I have asked a better question? The answers really were helpful, I thought.

Comment: @Matthew: In an ideal world it wouldn't be necessary to tighten up every question; unfortunately, in practice, the culture here is one that will quickly seize upon any opportunity to engage in poll behaviour (post one-liners or sequences of one-liners and vote indiscriminately). A targeted question on a specific form of stress unique to programmers would be great (we've had several), or a question about *quantifying* the various forms of *productivity loss* (as opposed to the more generic "stress") would also have been pretty useful. I'd be interested to know how you feel you've been helped.

Comment: @Aaronaught I should have phrased my question better. It was helpful to get an overview of the categories of stressors. Stress burns me out more quickly than most, so I was asking for wisdom in where boundaries are needed. I can figure out _how_ to set those boundaries, but I have trouble seeing clearly _where_ they are needed. You can't get that information from a question on a specific form of stress or quantifying efficiency.

Comment: @Aaronaught Furthermore, I know how to work efficiently and produce high quality results. So, neither a specific stressor nor performance quantification were the goal of my question.

Comment: @Matthew: On the one hand you say that stress burns you out, on the other hand you say it's not an issue of productivity. Which is it? If it's not about productivity then *what is "stress"*? How do you categorize it? Given that everybody has a different definition of *stress*, and everybody has wildly different tolerances to different influences, there is no possible example that *wouldn't* be correct for someone. Introverts are frustrated by chatter; extroverts are frustrated by solitude. If the goal of your question was to get a list of everyone's, then it's not a useful goal.

Comment: @Aaronaught I see what you're saying. Perhaps a better question would be that of _how_ an _introvert_ should _pace_ themselves (by way of managing stressors) so as to remain most _productive_ for the long haul. Rather than productivity 10-1-1-1-2-3-4 = 22, productivity 4-4-4-4-4-4-4 = 28. I did not make that clear in my question.

Comment: @Aaronaught Would that be a question less likely to be closed?

Comment: @Matthew: I can only speak for myself, not the community, but to me, that is a *way* better question because it demands more than just an "I'm stressed out by X" answer. I also think that, based on the revised definition, you could do away with the nebulous *stressors* term entirely and define it in terms of time and attention management (since every productivity loss attributable to another person is generally either due to distraction or quantifiable wasted time).

Comment: @Aaronaught Thanks for your take on it.

Answer (score 6):

I first looked at the question after it had been flagged: when I saw it, it had a couple of relatively decent answers and a couple of bad one-liner answers. I edited the question to try to get it away from being a list and to add the guidance.

Sometimes that works, sometimes that doesn't. In this case, it didn't look like it did. I've gone through the question and deleted all the answers that were clearly one-liners ignoring the guidance set out. If there are any other answers that clearly miss the point of the question, flag them as not an answer.

I personally think there is a potential for some good advice there: the question isn't just "What do you hate about programming?", it's "what are the things that cause stress for programmers, and how can one manage them?" But I'll leave it to the community to decide if the question needs to be ultimately closed.

Comment: +1 for deleting the one liners.

Comment: I completely agree with this.

Comment: I think the key guidance in the question is *what can we do to fix these situations?* which keeps it from being a random rant-fest.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't originally intending to answer my own question, but after some offline discussion it's become apparent that I should clarify what I think is wrong with the question:

1. The wording is vague. The definition of "stress" and "manage" is unclear, and indeed, if you look at the answers you'll see that different people had different interpretations.  Some thought of it in terms of productivity, others thought of it in terms of anxiety/job satisfaction, and not surprisingly of course, many considered it to be any kind of frustration.
2. It doesn't provide any criteria for evaluating the rightness or wrongness of an answer, which is one of the main litmus tests for constructiveness. Although the moderator note says to "back it up", neither the question nor the note really explain *how* one is supposed to back up such an answer, since stress is a very personal issue.
3. Although it is technically aimed at solving problems, it's not trying to solve a *single* problem, it's trying to solve an *arbitrarily large set* of problems.  That's extremely broad, and reminiscent of discussion forum mega-threads.
4. There's an entire *category* of specific questions here that could be asked - how do I manage unrealistic expectations, how do I gather better requirements, how do I solicit user feedback, how can I limit my other duties, etc.  All great questions by themselves, but this überquestion lazily asks for a hasty summary of *every* possible productivity factor, which (a) may discourage more specific questions from being asked, and (b) really doesn't give answerers a good opportunity to provide much substance or context.

So take your pick.  It's either too vague (NARQ), too broad (NARQ), too open-ended (NC), or a mass duplicate of all of the other [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career), [environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment), and [job](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) questions combined.  That's a lot of reasons to close.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing in that question or the answers that only pertains to programmers. Voted to close.

Answer (score -1):

Difficult for me to say. It was certainly a low signal/noise question but there *was* some signal in there. Joel's answer I think is useful enough to redeem a lot of the original question's faults.

Comment: No offense to Joel, he's a good contributor, but I don't really think his answer goes into any real depth with any of the specific items - it just has a lot of items, most of them obvious.  I don't think there's anybody who *just* learned about the stressful effects of a lack of respect or inappropriate deadlines from reading his answer. It's just telling people what they already know (or believe) and the upvoters are nodding their heads in agreement.

Comment: @Aaronaught good point. On the other hand, there's a difference between knowing something and being able to clearly enumerate it. Like, say, the definition of "stressor". The enumeration itself is valuable in that sense.

Comment: I'm not sure that the enumeration really helps to define anything. Take the definitions in my answer and apply them to his points; which ones match? It seems to vary; there's no consistent definition being used (except for the hopelessly trite "things I don't like"). His answer is well-written and all, but did it teach you anything or solve a problem for you? That's what we're supposed to be here for.

Comment: @Aaronaught I definitely see your point of view and its merits, I just don't find it completely compelling. No worries :)